# Computing integral by using variable transformation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-transforms

Let $I := \int_{(0,1)^2}\frac{1}{1-xy}\, d\lambda^2 (x,y)$.

Can someone help me to determine $I$ only buy using the transformations $u=\frac{1}{2} (y+x)$ and $v=\frac{1}{2} (y-x)$?
I don't know how to sketch the new integration area in order to find upper and lower limits of the new integral..

Comment: I have shown that $I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ (which was part of the total exercise), not sure if we need it for the problem above..

Comment: Please have a look at *proof 1* of R. Chapman's interesting paper: https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Curso/zeta2.pdf

Comment: Thanks. How does one find out the vertices of $S$ in the proof?

Comment: What do you denote as $\lambda(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Red: $x=0\implies u=v$

Blue: $y=0\implies u=-v$

Green: $x=1\implies u=v+1$

Yellow: $y=1\implies u=-v+1$.
$$
{1\over 1-xy}={1\over1-u^2+v^2}\\
{\partial(u,v)\over\partial(x,y)}=0.5\times0.5-0.5\times(-0.5)=0.5
$$
Integral over the gray area
$$
\int_{-0.5}^0\int_v^{-v}{0.5\over1-u^2+v^2}du dv
$$
Integral over the white area
$$
\int^{-0.5}_{-1}\int^{v+1}_{-v+1}{0.5\over1-u^2+v^2}du dv
$$

Comment: Nice thanks. But how do I get from the coloured lines of the first plot to the coloured line of the second plot? That is where my problem is.

Comment: @UserUser For example  $x=1\implies u=0.5(y+1),v=0.5(y-1)$. Now eliminate $y$ from these equations to get $u=v+1$. I edited my post a little.